# bash - How to pass a line feed to a script?

Tags: linux, bash, arguments, linefeed

Here is a simple script called **command.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "I received: |$1|"
```

When I call it with a line feed, it doesn't output it:

```
$ ./command.sh foo\
> bar
I received: |foobar|
```

Why does the line feed get lost?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call your script as:

```
./command.sh 'foo
> bar'
```

By placing `\` before newline you're merely breaking current command line and not really passing newline character to your script.

If you want to do it in single line then use:

```
./command.sh $'foo\nbar'
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. However, I have reworded my question. Can you please have a look at it here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38642827/363573 ?