# bash - How to pass a line feed to perl from within a bash script?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, perl, linefeed

I am trying to replace all digits sequences followed by a line feed and the letter `a`. Those digits sequences are located in a file called `test.txt`. The bash script `command.sh` is used to perform the task (see below).

**test.txt**

```
00
a1
b2
a
```

**command.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

MY_VAR="\d+
a"

grep -P "^.+$" test.txt | perl -pe "s/$MY_VAR/D/";
```

---

When I call the `command.sh` file, here is what I see:

```
$ ./command
00
a1
b2
a
```

However, I'm expecting this output:

```
$ ./command
D1
bD
```

What am I missing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321829/how-do-i-best-pass-arguments-to-a-perl-one-liner

Comment: `man perlrun` shows that `-p` will cause `perl` to run your command for each line. You can necessarily not replace multiline patterns in a single line. Try to get this working purely with `perl` first, and get to the `bash` part later

Comment: Possible duplicate [How to replace multiple any-character (including newline) in Perl RegEx?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36533282/2173773)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need `grep` since it is just matching `.+`, just use `perl` with `-0777` option (slurp mode) to match across the lines:

```
#!/bin/bash

MY_VAR="\d+
a"

perl -0777pe "s/$MY_VAR/D/g" test.txt
```

**Output:**

```
D1
bD
```

Comment: Technically, `-0777` is slurp mode (`-0` splits on null bytes). It makes no difference in this case, but it could in other (admittedly rare) scenarios.

Comment: Yes indeed `-0` splits file by null

Comment: The non use of `grep` is a great hint. However, it introduces a new problem resumed in a new question. Would you mind see it? http://stackoverflow.com/q/38656531/363573

Comment: note: bash is not passing variable to perl but generates perl command with newline, injection may be done if variable contains `/` (regex delimiter), safier solution is to pass by evironment or by argument