# How to pivot data in Perl with regex only?

Tags: regex

I want to turn some data on multiple lines into one line with a regular expression.

The data consists in start and end notifications of HTTP exchanges followed by details written on one or more lines. Here is the regex for doing the job:

```
(\d+-\d+-\d+) (\d+:\d+:\d+,\d+) INFO  (\[com\.LoggingFilter\]) \(([^)]+)\) (\d+) \* Server in-bound request
(?=\5 > (.+)
[\s\S]*
\5 > user-agent:\s*(.+)
[\s\S]*
(\d+-\d+-\d+) (\d+:\d+:\d+,\d+) INFO  \3 \(\4\) \5 \* Server out-bound response
\5 < (\d+)
[\s\S]*)
```

It (almost) works: [VIEW regex in action](https://regex101.com/r/oA6qK0/2). Some details (preserved by the positive look ahead) are still kept after the regex replacement. How to get the following result

```
"88598";"2016-07-29";"00:00:08,262";"2016-07-29";"00:00:08,262";"http-10.2.3.4-8080-14";"Java/1.7.0_79";"303";"GET http://1.2.3.4:8080/service/api/
"88599";"2016-07-29";"00:00:08,382";"2016-07-29";"00:00:08,382";"http-10.2.3.4-8080-8";"Java/1.7.0_79";"303";"GET http://1.2.3.4:8080/service/api/"
(...)
```

instead of

```
"88598";"2016-07-29";"00:00:08,262";"2016-07-29";"00:00:08,262";"http-10.2.3.4-8080-14";"Java/1.7.0_79";"303";"GET http://1.2.3.4:8080/service/api/"88598 > GET http://1.2.3.4:8080/service/api/
<garbage data here>
"88599";"2016-07-29";"00:00:08,382";"2016-07-29";"00:00:08,382";"http-10.2.3.4-8080-8";"Java/1.7.0_79";"303";"GET http://1.2.3.4:8080/service/api/"88599 > GET http://1.2.3.4:8080/service/api/
(...)
```

Comment: You have given us your regex, the output you're getting and the output that you want to get. That's all great. What we're missing is an example of the input data.

Comment: @DaveCross It is in the regex demo.

Comment: Doing that "with regex only" is a bad approach (inefficient), you should consider a line by line or a block approach.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
(\d+-\d+-\d+) (\d+:\d+:\d+,\d+) INFO  (\[com\.LoggingFilter\]) \(([^)]+)\) (\d+) \* Server in-bound request
(?=\5 > (.+)
[\s\S]*
\5 > user-agent:\s*(.+)
[\s\S]*
(\d+-\d+-\d+) (\d+:\d+:\d+,\d+) INFO  \3 \(\4\) \5 \* Server out-bound response
\5 < (\d+)
[\s\S]*)[\s\S]*?((?=\n.*Server in-bound request)|(?![\s\S]))
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/tS9aD7/1) the demo.

Comment: If `Server in-bound request` appear in the garbage, it is saved in the final result. See: https://regex101.com/r/tS9aD7/2

Comment: In some way you should have a criterion in order to distinguish garbage from non-garbage stuff. If `\n.*Server in-bound request` could appear in garbage, replace it with something that more unlikely will appear. For example the entire `\n\d+-\d+-\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+,\d+ INFO +\[com\.LoggingFilter\] \([^)]+\) \d+ \* Server in-bound request`? See [here](https://regex101.com/r/tS9aD7/3).

Comment: Your pattern need a lot of steps to find the match and I suspect the real file to be larger than the sample. Consequence with this pattern you may quickly reach the backtracking limit. Even if I think that the *only regex approach* isn't appropriate, I tried to improve the pattern to reduce the number of steps. You will find the result here: https://regex101.com/r/lT4vV4/1